# Error in opening axml file in Visual studio 15

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, windows-7

[image]

When I am trying to open a axml file in Visual Studio 15 then below error is coming. I am using windows 7 OS. Any body please help on this!!

> "Something went wrong"
>   mono.android.DesignerException
>       at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:43)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:177)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:228)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:693)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.disposeSystem(Resources_Delegate.java:83)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.disposeResources(BridgeContext.java:242)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.tearDown(RenderAction.java:257)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.release(RenderAction.java:220)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:438)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:222)
>       ... 4 more

PFA the screen shot

Comment: Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your AndroidManifest file. See the minSdkVersion and download that version on SDK Manager (install "Tools" and "Extras" folder's too).
Recompile your solution and restart.

:)